# Cannot Call RemoveWorkflowFromListItem in Powershell

Tags: workflow, powershell

I got the following line of code:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::RemoveWorkflowFromListItem($wf);
```

I receive the error

> Method invocation failed because
>   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager] doesn't contain a
>   method named 'RemoveWorkflowFromListItem'

while other methods from workflowmanager (like "CancelWorkflow") work

Comment: You should use `RemoveWorkflowFromListItem` from `site.WorkflowManager`

Comment: CancelWorkflow is a static method of SPWorkflowManager, so the syntax below is correct:
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::CancelWorkflow($wf);
You should call the instance method via an object reference as suggested by Amal Hashim

Comment: CancelWorkflow is a static method of SPWorkflowManager, so the syntax below is correct:

Comment: @OleAlbers Cool. I have posted it as answer. Hope it helps the community

Comment: So in the end is there a difference between CancelWorkflow and RemoveWorkflowFromListItem ? Do they do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `RemoveWorkflowFromListItem` from `site.WorkflowManager`